# Why does a test pass if run as "rake cucumber:wip" and fail as "rake cucumber:all"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a feature file and step definitions.  I put @wip at the top of the feature file.  Then I run

```
rake cucumber:wip
```

and I get 8 passed tests, no fails.
Then all I do is remove the @wip from the feature file and run

```
rake cucumber:all
```

and one of my step definitions fails with a nil pointer.
I can only think of two things:
  1. there is a difference between the wip and default profiles, but when I look in cucumber.rake file they appear to be the same
  2. there is something about running my feature tests with the other feature tests or database transactions that is wiping something out.
Has anybody seen something like this before?

Rails 2.2.2
cucumber 0.7.2
cucumber-rails 0.3.1

Answer (score 2):

`rake cucumber:wip` runs cucumber with the `--wip` switch.

This makes cucumber "revert" the results of scenarios: if an error occurs during execution it "succeeds"; if all steps run smoothly, it reports a failure.

The idea is that if all steps run without errors, it is not a "work in progress" and shouldn't be considered (tagged) as such anymore.

Comment: Understood, but this is not the issue.  All the tests pass when using the WIP tag.  It is NOT that some fail and because I am using the wip tag, cucumber says that is OK.  The pointer is NOT nil when run with the wip tag and it is nil when run with the OK tag.

Comment: Then I guess we'd need more info to help you. `--trace`?